# I want my discord bot to write a messsage when a specific member goes online

Tags: python, discord, bots

I can't seem to  figure out how to make the bot check the status of a specific member.

````
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True


client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if after.status.name == 'online':
        await client.get_channel("channel_id").send("message")```
````

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the documentation, and some examples.. I think this should fix  it. What we're doing here is we're checking the status of the "after", which is a member object. Upon checking the documentation, I didn't find status.name, so I changed it to become str(after.status). You can then add the channel ID and it should work as planned. Let me know if there are any errors!

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
memberid = '123'


client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
  if after.id == memberid: # "after" is a member object, so we can check the id if its the same as the "specific member"
    if str(after.status) == 'online': #check status
        await client.get_channel("channel_id").send("message")
```